# lo,hi indices in recursive binarysearch in java

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

For a classic binarySearch on an array of java Strings (say `String[] a`), which is the correct way of calling the search method? is it

```
binarySearch(a,key,0,a.length)
```

or

```
binarySearch(a,key,0,a.length-1)
```

I tried both for the below implementation,and both seems to work.. Is there a usecase where either of these calls can fail?

```
class BS{
    public static int binarySearch(String[] a,String key){
        return binarySearch(a,key,0,a.length);
        //return binarySearch(a,key,0,a.length-1);
    }
    public static int binarySearch(String[] a,String key,int lo,int hi)   {
        if(lo > hi){
            return -1;
        }
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;
        if(less(key,a[mid])){
            return binarySearch(a,key,lo,mid-1);
        }
        else if(less(a[mid],key)){
            return binarySearch(a,key,mid+1,hi);
        }
        else{
            return mid;
        }

    }
    private static boolean less(String x,String y){
        return x.compareTo(y) < 0;
    }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = {"D","E","F","M","K","I"};
        Arrays.sort(a);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        int x =  binarySearch(a,"M");
        System.out.println("found at :"+x);

     }
}
```

Comment: The most stable approach would be `Arrays.binarySearch(a, "M")`. They got their code tested many more times, then we could ever test ours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case where

a = [ "foo" ]

and you search key "zoo" with `binarySearch(a,key,0,a.length);`

The code will search for it in interval[0,1], see it should be right than that, 
next recursion searches interval [1,1], causing an indexing of a[1] at line

```
if(less(key,a[mid])){
```

resulting in a array out of bounds error.

The second solution will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the second approach will be safe.

Consider this case - you have an array of 9 elements and the key is situated at the last index (8-th element). Then you might have a method call like this if you follow the first approach -

```
binarySearch(a, key, 9, 9);
```

Now, in that method execution, the integer division in the following line will result in 9 -

```
int mid = 9 + (9 - 9)/2;
```

and you will be indexing your array with 9 in the next line -

```
if( less(key,a[mid]) ) { // You'll face ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException
    ....
}
```

which will be invalid and cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

The second approach however will be just fine.